# Virtual keyboard overlaps a WebBrowser component

Tags: android, ios, delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.2.2.

I have a `TWebBrowser` component in my FireMonkey multi-device application, and it works fine.  However, I would like for my application to reshape itself so that the virtual keyboard does not overlap the edit component of the WebBrowser.

I tried to use a `TVerticalScrollBox` component to solve this overlapping situation, and it works fine on iOS, but the problem continues on Android.

Is there any solution to this issue?

**IOs example:**(What i want)
[image]

**Android example:**(My problem)
[image]

Comment: The Firemonkey implementation of the web browser is in a terrible, terrible condition last I knew. It doesn't even let you hide it, or put it on an invisible panel. It still bleeds through to the user. This is due to the nature of the rendering engine.

Comment: @Jerry Do you know another way to use an embedded website in my application?

Comment: Did you solve this?